# Unable to prove that only 0 is less than 1 with mathcomp's finTypes

Tags: coq, proof

This question might seem very stupid, but I'm unable to prove that the only natural number
less than 1 is 0. I'm using mathcomp's finType library, and the goal that I want to prove is:

```
Lemma ord0_eq1 (a : ordinal 1) : a = ord0.
```

The problem is that if I destruct `a` and `ord0` I obtain the following goal:

```
∀ (m : nat) (i : (m < 1)%N), Ordinal i = Ordinal (ltn0Sn 0)
```

Now I may use `case` and derive absurd if m is not equal to 0. But if m is equal to 0, I get:

```
∀ i : (0 < 1)%N, Ordinal i = Ordinal (ltn0Sn 0)
```

And the only way to prove this equality is to prove that `forall i : 0 < 1, i = (ltn0Sn 0)`.
But I don't know how to prove equality between two proofs of the same `Prop` without using
proof irrelevance, and I don't want to add an axiom to my theory.
There must be some way to use Ssreflect's reflection capabilities to solve this goal, but I
haven't found anything: I can get to the point where I need to prove the equality between two
proofs of an equality and I could use UIP (uniqueness of identity proofs), but that's another
axiom and I don't want to use it.

I can't believe that I have to add an axiom to prove this goal: the
less-than relation can only be determined by computation. There should be
a way to prove that `forall (m n : nat) (a b : m < n), a = b` without UIP or proof irrelevance.

Thanks

**EDIT**: I am using mathcomp's `ssrnat` library and not Coq's `Arith` module. The `"<"` notation is bound to ssrnat's `ltn`, not to Arith's `lt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predicate defining the `ordinal` type is a boolean equality, hence satisfies proof irrelevance.  In cases like this, you can appeal to `val_inj`:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Lemma ord0_eq1 (a : ordinal 1) : a = ord0.
Proof. by apply/val_inj; case: (val a) (valP a). Qed.
```

Comment: That's the correct answer, if you want to complete the low-level proof all that you need is to use `eq_axiomK`

Comment: I haven't really understood how does this work, but it seems very interesting so I'll go and study the manual. Thanks a lot!